# Using Random Number Generator In Play

Tags: playframework

How can I use a random number generator in play such as or the equivalent to java.util.Random?

Such as:

```
@Random r = new Random();
@for(p <- products) {
    @if(p.getId==@r.nextInt(25)+1){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close!  You would define your `Random` object in your Play/Twirl template like so:

```
@r = @{ 
  new java.util.Random
}
```

Then your original `for` loop should work as expected, though you'll have to rewrite your `if` condition to only have one `@`, i.e.

```
@if(p.getId == r.nextInt(25) + 1){
```